# trigger priority and response to said triggers mtg

Tags: magic-the-gathering

if there are two voltaic servant triggers, can i respond to the second trigger after the first trigger resolves? For example; I tap steel overseer during my turn. At the end of my turn my two voltaic servants trigger to untap a target artifact. I untap my steel overseer for the first trigger and in response to the second trigger I tap steel overseer again. After that the second trigger goes off and I will have effectively tapped steel overseer 2 times and untapped 3 times because of the two voltaic servants. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Players get priority after each spell/ability resolves.

Comment: Your use of "first" and "second" is backwards, though. The second ability added resolves first.

Comment: Also, one doesn't respond to "triggers", but to spells and abilities (including triggered abilities). "Trigger goes off" is a really confusing way to say "triggered ability resolves".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, this is correct.**

---

Rule 117.1b states:

> 117.1b A player may activate an activated ability any time they have priority.

And rule 117.3b states:

> 117.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.

Based on that, you will receive priority after the first trigger resolves, and may activate [Steel Overseer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSteel%20Overseer%5d)'s ability, putting it on the stack. After *that* resolves and each player passes priority, the [Voltaic Servant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVoltaic%20Servant%5d)'s ability still on the stack resolves normally, untapping target artifact.

Comment: Thanks. I saw something similar before I asked this question, but I didn't see it address the particular point of being able to respond to the stack. I figured that was the case but I wanted to double check. Thanks.